# How can I allow multiple users to access/edit a microsoft access database?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

Now I know right off the bat that Microsoft access isn't the ideal client for multiple users accessing it but it's the only one I've got right now. I have built a small program as a sort of inventory management system. There are currently three users that will be using it regularly and at the same time. One issue I am running into with this is that sometimes the database will not be accessible and will give an error stating that the file is already in use by "so and so" user. The other issue is that I'm getting a similar error every now and then where it states "The database has been placed in a state by user  on machine  that prevents it from being opened or locked". I am connecting to the database through an ACE OLEDB connection using the line below

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=P:\Tool & Cutter Grinding\Tool Cutter Database.accdb;Persist Security Info = False"
```

I have also changed some of the settings in the actual access database such as:

1. Enable all macros
2. Add the folder the database is in to the trusted locations list
3. Confirm that the database is set to open in shared mode by default

I don't know if there is something small I've missed or a setting I need to change but as of yet, the problem is still persisting.

Below is an example of how I am using the database. I am using string based SQL commands but am not too familiar with `DataSet`/`DataTable`/etc. items, so I may be doing something incorrectly.

```
 'close connection from any previous session
    con.Close()

    'clear dataset so as not to append data
    ds.Clear()

    'Select SQL query that selects ALL records from a table
    Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM " & "[" & table & "]" & ""
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=P:\Tool & Cutter Grinding\Tool Cutter Database.accdb;Persist Security Info = False"

    'use try catch statement to open the connection
    Try
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Convert.ToString(ex))
    End Try

    'use try catch statement to add a table (dt) to the dataset (ds) in order to store values
    Try
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    'create new dataadapter object using the sql string from above and the connection created above
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(str, con)

    'create new command builder in order to excecute the SELECT SQL statement using the dataadapter created (da)
    'specify prefix and suffix for cb
    Dim cb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da) With {
        .QuotePrefix = "[",
        .QuoteSuffix = "]"
    }

    'use try catch statement to fill the datatable (dt) using the dataadapter (da)
    Try
        da.Fill(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Convert.ToString(ex))
    End Try

    'set the datasource of the datagridview to the datatable
    dgv.DataSource = dt.DefaultView

    'close the connection to the database
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Are there users that are opening the database directly, or is it just through your program?

Comment: How are you accessing the data?  Show an example.  My experience with MS Access through .Net is never use Access Queries — always call your sql string directly.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The users are only accessing the database through the program. I do open the database every now and then to check on the data and gather information.

Comment: @LarsTech I am using string based sql queries to do all of my select/update/insert functions. Ill add an example at the end of my question

Comment: The `sometimes the database will not be accessible` really hints that someone is probably opening the database in exclusive mode through the Access program.

Comment: You need to make sure you do things like dispose of connections and datareaders in the smallest scope possible - the code shown doesnt.  Also probably bundle updates into small groups so that the DB is never tied up any longer than needed.  And then you open the file, do it without exclusive access.

Comment: @LarsTech That may be true, I am the only one that has access installed on their computer so it would have to be me. Is there a way to make sure it does not open in exclusive mode other than changing the default opening setting to shared?

Comment: @Plutonix That makes sense. Would you be able to elaborate on what you mean by that? Would I just be able to add more con.open() and con.close() lines to achieve that or do you recommend i rewrite some of my code? As of right now this is the only way i know how to open and manipulate a database

Comment: I'm trying to be helpful by saying this...your comments should gear more toward the why and the bigger picture of the purpose of the code. The comments you have are describing what the code is currently doing. It's like reading a comment and then reading the comment again, but in code.

Comment: @MichaelZ. Understandable! Writing comments are kind of a new thing for me so I have a bad habit of making them too simple or redundant just to get it over with. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Back-End Access DB file. File > Options > Client Settings. For your Use Case No Locks should be fine, but Edited record setting will work as well if you need it

[image: Image of Back-End Access File]

Comment: I had not heard of splitting a database before this. It sounds like it could help the strain of multiple users on the database. Ill try to split it and see how that works. Would i need to change anything in the VB side of things in terms of how I am referencing the database or getting information from it?

Comment: I believe that you had mentioned in the comments above that you are referencing the DB through a program. I removed the section in my answer containing that information. Are you using an Access Form to interact with the DB? or are you using your own program?

Comment: I am using my own program to interact with the database. I have split the database and restarted the program but it is still giving me the same errors as before

Comment: Splitting the database will be of no use to you then. Splitting is for when you are using Access forms to interact with the DB

Comment: Oh alright I see, thank you for trying to help anyways! Is there anything else you can think of that might help?

Comment: Have you tried my edited answer? This is still relevant for your use case

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting the default record locking to both no locks and edited record. Neither of them has worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148539/discussion-between-chance-finley-and-nickhallick).

Answer (score 0):

> but its [sic] the only one I've got right now

Actually, it's not.

Have a look at SQL Server Compact. It's free, it's small and it handles multiple users with aplomb.

You can add all the references you need using NuGet.